# What is the next?

Tags: lateral-thinking, sequence

[image]

- 1 3 5
- 2 4 ?

some numbers are given, it seems so obvious?

FYI: the answer is not 6.

> what is the next?

the answer is not a number.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-next-number-after-1-2-3-4-5-The-answer-is-not-6 hmm...

Comment: Oh, some of them were funny/cool

Comment: That's why I put it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> **R** (or B)

since

> this corresponds to Reverse (or Back) on a gearbox.

The answer is (not)

> 8

since

> $s(n) = 2 \times s(n-2) + s(n-1)$

Comment: intended answer is R :) please edit and i will accept it

Comment: Ohh, that was there on quora

Answer (score 6):

As stated in your question, the answer is:

> "not 6"

Comment: haha :) i like it though this is not the answer that i thought :)

Comment: Well, lateral thinking stroke again :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer *should* be:

> "everybody in the car, so come on let's ride"

As per

> [Lou Bega's rendition of "Mambo No. 5"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EK_LN3XEcnw)...
>
>  One, two, three, four, five everybody in the car, so come on
>  Let's ride to the liquor store around the corner
>  The boys say they want some gin and juice
>  But I really don't wanna, beer bust like I had last week
>  I must stay deep because talk is cheap
>
>  I like Angela, Pamela, Sandra and Rita
>  And as I continue you know they are getting sweeter
>  So what can I do I really beg you my Lord
>  To me is flirting it's just like sport, anything fly
>  It's all good let me dump it please set in the trumpet
>
>  A little bit of Monica in my life, a little bit of Erica by my side
>  A little bit of Rita is all I need, a little bit of Tina is what I see
>  A little bit of Sandra in the sun, a little bit of Mary all night long
>  A little bit of Jessica here I am, a little bit of you makes me your man
>
>  Mambo number five
>
>  Jump up and down and move it all around
>  Shake your head to the sound, put your hand on the ground
>  Take one step left and one step right
>  One to the front and one to the side
>  Clap your hand once and clap your hands twice
>  And if it looks like this then you are doing it right
>
>  A little bit of Monica in my life, a little bit of Erica by my side
>  A little bit of Rita is all I need, a little bit of Tina is what I see
>  A little bit of Sandra in the sun, a little bit of Mary all night long
>  A little bit of Jessica here I am, a little bit of you makes me your man
>
>  Trumpet, the trumpet
>
>  Mambo number five
>
>  A little bit of Monica in my life, a little bit of Erica by my side
>  A little bit of Rita is all I need, a little bit of Tina is what I see
>  A little bit of Sandra in the sun, a little bit of Mary all night long
>  A little bit of Jessica here I am, a little bit of you makes me your man
>  I do all to fall in love with a girl like you
>  'Cause you can't run and you can't hide
>  You and me gonna touch the sky
>
>  Mambo number five!

Comment: So close **:)**